# Is it good option to host Java based web applications on SalesForce

Tags: integration, developer, website-integration

can anyone explain me the following queries regarding web application hosting on `Salesforce` since i am very much new to the `Salesforce`

1. Can we deploy enterprise java based web application? or should i go with normal cloud service providers
2. Pros and Cons of hosting on it
3. Can we perform C`Continuous Integration and Deployment` on it?

Comment: You should probably check out [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)

Comment: Did you even read any single paragraph about Salesforce or Force.com platform?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with how Salesforce works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No.
2. Salesforce is not a Java hosting provider.
3. Yes.

You should probably look into running Java apps on Heroku (which is a Salesforce company) 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/java

Comment: Cool... Thanks @Mark Pond. Then i will go with `AWS, GCP`. Anyhow thanks once agin